# Adding a calculated column to a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am attempting to add a column in my query (see bottom) by multiplying two of the columns together and grouping by the item number, but I get the following error:

> Column 'IV00102.LOCNCODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I am sure this is a simple solution that has been covered on here, but I was unable to find what I was looking for. Any help would be much appreciated

```
 SELECT        
     IV00101.ITEMNMBR, IV00102.LOCNCODE, IV00102.BINNMBR, IV00101.STNDCOST,
     IV00101.CURRCOST, IV00101.USCATVLS_3, IV00101.USCATVLS_4, 
     IV00101.USCATVLS_2, IV00102.QTYONHND, 
     SUM(IV00101.CURRCOST * IV00102.QTYONHND) AS 'CxQ'
 FROM            
     IV00101 
 INNER JOIN
     IV00102 ON IV00101.ITEMNMBR = IV00102.ITEMNMBR
 WHERE
     IV00102.LOCNCODE <> ''
 GROUP BY
     IV00101.ITEMNMBR;
```

Comment: The error message tells you what the issue is, every column must either be a grouping column (such as ItemNmbr) or an aggregate.  I would suggest adding sample expected output, because your query and description don't match

Answer (score 0):

Selection colums need to add in `GROUP BY` except aggregate column

```
  SELECT        IV00101.ITEMNMBR, IV00102.LOCNCODE, IV00102.BINNMBR, IV00101.STNDCOST, IV00101.CURRCOST, IV00101.USCATVLS_3, IV00101.USCATVLS_4, IV00101.USCATVLS_2, 
                                 IV00102.QTYONHND,
     SUM(IV00101.CURRCOST*IV00102.QTYONHND) AS 'CxQ'
        FROM            IV00101 INNER JOIN
                                 IV00102 ON IV00101.ITEMNMBR = IV00102.ITEMNMBR
        WHERE               IV00102.LOCNCODE <> ''

        GROUP BY        IV00101.ITEMNMBR,IV00102.LOCNCODE, IV00102.BINNMBR, IV00101.STNDCOST, IV00101.CURRCOST, IV00101.USCATVLS_3, IV00101.USCATVLS_4, IV00101.USCATVLS_2, 
                                 IV00102.QTYONHND
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find this easier with `apply`:

```
SELECT i1.*, i2.CxQ
FROM IV00101 i1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT i2.ITEMNMBR, SUM(i1.CURRCOST * i2.QTYONHND) as CxQ
      FROM IV00102 i2
      WHERE i2.ITEMNMBR = i1.ITEMNMBR AND
            i2.LOCNCODE <> ''
    ) i2;
```

Also note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.